# Powershell: Cannot convert value to type System.String

Tags: powershell

I have an array of Reciepients:

```
$reciepientList = @(
    "foo"
    "bar"
    #...
)
```

I want to send a Message to all of them with a function using REST:

```
function Send-Message{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$Message,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$Reciepient
    )
# My RESTful stuff goes here ...
Invoke-RestMethod ...
}
```

**Sending my message fails:**

```
Send-Message -Reciepient $reciepientList -Message "My message"
```

Output:

```
Send-Message: Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Reciepient'.
Cannot convert value to type System.String.
```

Any idea, how to tell Powershell to convert my Array to a String?

Comment: Your `$reciepientList` is not a Hash, but a string **array**. Change the parameter type casting from `[string]` to `[string[]]`. (`[parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String[]]$Reciepient`), or join the email addresses with a semi-colon (`;`), depending if your Send-Message function needs a combined string or an array of recipients.

Comment: You could also leave the function unchanged, instead expand the list and process each item separately  
`$reciepientList | % { Send-Message -Reciepient $_ -Message "Your message" }`

Answer (score 2):

@Theo: Thanks for pointing me to the type casting. It has solved my issue!

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][String]$Message,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][String[]]$Reciepient
)
```